# How to automatically click a link when the website loads

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to figure out how to make an anchor link clicked when the website is visited. I would be grateful if someone can help me, here's a demo code, you can match the id for my ease thank you.

```
<body>
<a id='deepakkamat' href='http://mywebpage.com'> This is my webpage </a>
</body>
```

So i want to know any JavaScript code to make the link clicked when the page loads. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jquery answer:

```
$($('#deepakkamat').click());
```

This will actually register a click event as the cause, but it seems awfully unnecessary. The meta method is the preferred method.

Comment: This is an old question and now it feels very awkward to see these posts. It can't be deleted so I better accept the best answer for others.

Comment: @DeepakKamat: Wait until you're looking at some of your answers/questions from a few years ago. That's when it really gets awkward :)

Answer (score 3):

Use the meta tag to redirect to another page when the page loads:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=http://www.example.com/" />
```

Where `2` is the number of seconds before the redirect occurs.

This will be more reliable and more straightforward than writing JavaScript to click a link. Let me know how it works for you.

Comment: Hello sir, actually this will not work for me, i want a JavaScript that will click the link when the page loads, the link the id. Sir please tell me if there's a way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

When you're trying to archive a redirect, use `document.location.href = "http://mywebpage.com"` (or the meta tag mentioned before).

There is also a `click` method available, so that you can run

```
document.getElementById("deepakkamat").click()​​​;​
```