# Use Javascript to auto-click in web page when it loads

Tags: javascript

How I can make a script to automatically click in html web page when it loads?
there is people in some forums selling scripts like that!!.
script for auto page scrolling and auto clicking. so i need to make a script for auto clicking in any area in the page

Have you good day & thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to automatically click a link when the website loads](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10817056/how-to-automatically-click-a-link-when-the-website-loads)

Answer (score -1):

There's a few things you need to do

- Wait for the "page" to finish loading. In this case we need to wait until the HTML elements have loaded.
- Find the element you want to click on
- Fire off the click event on that element

`<script>
      //DOMContentLoaded is when we know that the HTML elements are ready
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
        //find your element
        var yourElement = document.getElementById('yourElement');
        //fire off click event on that element
        yourElement.click();
      });
    </script>`